# Writing a Python node that publishes AND subscribes to topics of different message frequency

Tags: ros, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to write a node in Python that subscribes to a topic and listens to another.

One way I have managed to do that is by issuing the **publish command in the callback**. However, this approach only lets my node publish when a new message comes in from the topic it is subscribed to. So **my publisher is "constrained" to the subscribed topic's frequency**.

**Is there an other way to do this?** I've looked online and couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance,
Ernest

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53394/writing-a-python-node-that-publishes-and-subscribes-to-topics-of-different-message-frequency/) by [Ernest](https://answers.ros.org/users/4002/ernest/) on ROS Answers with karma: 341 on 2013-01-25

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An example might look like this (roughly):

```
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Int32

class Echo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0

        rospy.init_node('echoer')
               
        self.pub = rospy.Publisher('/out_value', Int32, latch=True)
        rospy.Subscriber('/in_value', Int32, self.update_value)
    
    def update_value(self, msg):
        self.value = msg.data

    def run(self):
        r = rospy.Rate(10)
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            self.pub.publish(self.value)
            r.sleep()
```

---

Originally posted by [isherman](https://answers.ros.org/users/2938/isherman/) with karma: 132 on 2013-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on 2016-12-30**:
Do you need to add rospy.Spin() below the subscriber line?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the [python publisher tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(python), talker.py shows an example of publishing outside a subscriber callback using a loop at a specified rate.

You can use this sort of publishing scheme when you don't have a sequential processing task. If you have additional subscribers in your python script, they will continue to run at whatever rate the messages come in in their own individual threads.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2013-01-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4